# Is there a way to run GQL queries without defining entity model in python

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I have a java, spring-data app that uses Datastore. I need a subset of this data to run analytics using python app. What I need in python app is essentially a join (yup, relational doesnt get out of me) between two "Kinds" queried by key of one kind.
[NDB client](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/queries) requires creating same entity models in python to be able to query data, which is a drag. Why cant i simply run the console version of GQL(select * from `kind`) using python. Maybe I am missing something as this sort of querying is available in almost all relational and nosql DBs.

Answer (score 0):

Your observations are correct: a GQL query cannot perform a SQL-like "join" query. This is documented on the [GQL Reference for Python NDB/DB](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/gqlreference) documentation page.

If you would like to submit a feature request to request its implementation, you can simply open an issue for it in the [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/).

Comment: Thanks @George. Lets say I can replace join with something else like a subquery, even then is there a way to just call a plain GQL (select * from `kind`) without providing entity definition in python as a class?

Comment: In the Python Datastore API, an entity's kind is determined by its model class, which you define in your application as a subclass of the data modeling library class db.Model. This is documented in the [Kinds and identifiers](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/entities#Kinds_and_identifiers) sub-chapter. 

It is otherwise unclear how you plan to use results from the select statement in your code, without an appropriate class to care for properties.